# How to check in Laravel if a POST request comes with form data or a JSON body? For a webhook API

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks, laravel-request

I've created a webhook endpoint and now receiving requests with my Laravel application.

If request comes with the form data, I use `$request->post();`, if it has a json body I use `$request->getContent()`.

I understand that there may not be both. Right?

My question is - how can I check if response comes with the form data or json body?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want check , whether request is Ajax or form data?

You can check this by using:

```
$request->ajax()
```

Or by http headers.

Comment: I'm getting this `Method Illuminate\Http\Request::isAjax does not exist.`

Comment: there is a `->isJson() ` method, but it is always  `false` for me, even there is a raw body or a form data

Comment: Try: $request->ajax();

Comment: same, it is always `false`. I'm testing it from google postman and I try different types of body to see the difference. But `ajax` method always return `false`

Comment: So, check headers (content-type):

`Route::get('/test',function(Request $request){
    dd($request->header('content-type'));
});`

Comment: I can set any headers with google postman. And still laravel knows, when to return data via `$request->post();` and when to return in via `$request->getContent()`. And I cannot find the condition checking function.